# How to find out where in code event receiver is being added using developer tools

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find where in code an event receiver is added to a div, i have 7 JS files added by previous developer and they are too long to share.

What I am looking for is to find a way, to figure out where in code an event receiver is added on a tool, maybe a line number, this is what I get in chrome developer tools,

[image]

Comment: looking for  div#icon handler

Comment: Interesting and practical question, since jQuery binds the final events it's displayed as the source, but an actual back-link could be very practical for debugging straight in the browser.

Comment: @Nit meh. just `grep` the sucker.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин That's not always possible since the binding may be passed through numerous function calls, the item ID might be concatenated from different strings etc.

Comment: Then the debugger won't save you